# Visual Studio 2008 forces me to Rebuild Web Site every time to effect any changes I make

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, web, rebuild

I have been using Visual Studio 2008 for the past 2 years or so. Recently, in 2 particular ASP.NET (with VB.NET) web sites I am forced to do a Rebuild Solution after any change, no matter how minor, even if it's just an HTML change.

In other words, I cannot load the application into the browser and make an HTML change and hit F5 as the change would not be reflected in the browser. Also, if I make a change in the code and try to run the project by clicking F5 the code change would not come into effect. I first have to rebuild, then hit F5, which obviously takes much more time.

Does anyone know why this may be happening? This does not happen with all of my projects but only with 2 in particular.

Thanks in advance,
Tim

Comment: Please post your project file. You can open it in WordPad and paste the XML here.

Comment: Are the projects Web Application projects or Web site projects and are they accessed using the Visual Studio build in web server or local IIS?

Comment: @duckworth - exactly what I was going to guess about.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments...I am using the type of project which does not include .Designer files or .resx files, not sure which terminology though...created using "File->New Web Site". I created a virtual directory in IIS and open the site through IIS...

Answer (score 3):

Oh the joy of visual studio and web projects!

Things to try:

- Clear the VSWebCache (this is usually at %USERPROFILE%\VSWebCache)
- Clear Temporary ASP.NET Files (at %WINDIR% %WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files - make sure you keep the security if you delete this top level folder rather than the subfolders)
- If you keep your machine on all the time (never a good plan for a development machine), then run iisreset

Comment: Hi David,

Thanks for your reply. I have already cleared by Temporary ASP.NET files and I switch off my machine every day. However, I cannot find the "VSWebCache" folder under the %USERPROFILE% folder...and this seems to be the last thing to try apparently...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Super-late, but: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/09/22/Tip_2F00_Trick_3A00_-Optimizing-ASP.NET-2.0-Web-Project-Build-Performance-with-VS-2005.aspx

The meat:

- turn off "build web site as part of a solution" in the site's property pages' "build" section.
- change the drop-down to "build page" in the same location.
- manually build-page to force an update.  It even works with my issue, where it won't update any WebMethod()s.

If you see this, let me know if it works!